# Duda de useState en arreglos React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

estoy creando una aplicacion en React y tengo que mostrar en pantalla un arreglo el cual contiene varias etiquetas en cada uno de los indices del arreglo , cada item tiene dos botones uno de realizado y uno de pagado , que cambian de color cada que les das click(para esto ocupo el hook de useState)

pero al momento de dar click cambia el estado de todos los botones en el componente , como puedo hacer que cada boton cambie de manera independiente?

```
  const [getPagado, setPagado] = useState(false)
  const [getClassButtonPagado, setClassButtonPagado] = useState('icon unpay')
  const [getClassButtonRealizado, setClassButtonRealizado] = useState('icon unpay')
  let arrayFragments = []
  const dibujarTratamientos = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      arrayFragments[i] = (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Invoice className='animated'>
            <Info>
              <ConfigurationElementsDiv>
                <BiEditAlt className='conf' />
                <BiEraser className='conf' />
              </ConfigurationElementsDiv>
              <TextContainer>
                <Title>Resina</Title>
                <SubTitle>Fecha</SubTitle>
              </TextContainer>
              <ConfigurationElementsDiv>
                <FaTooth className='tooth' />
                <Price>#16</Price>
              </ConfigurationElementsDiv>


            </Info>
            <Container>
              <BiDollarCircle className={getClassButtonPagado} onClick={() => {
                if (getPagado) {
                  setClassButtonPagado('icon unpay')
                  setPagado(false)
                } else if (!getPagado) {
                  setClassButtonPagado('icon pay')
                  setPagado(true)
                }
              }} />
              <BiBadgeCheck className={getClassButtonRealizado} onClick={() => {
                if (getRealizado) {
                  setClassButtonRealizado('icon unpay')
                  setRealizado(false)
                } else if (!getRealizado) {
                  setClassButtonRealizado('icon pay')
                  setRealizado(true)
                }

              }} />
              <Price>$ 1,200.87</Price>
            </Container>
          </Invoice>
        </React.Fragment>

      );
    }
    return arrayFragments;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias agregar un state que fuera un arreglo con los objetos que quieres mostrar.
Un ejemplo:

```
const Componente = () => {

    const [fragments, setFragments] = useState([])

    const arreglo = [{
        title: 'Resina',
        subtitle: 'Fecha', 
        Price: '#16',
        pagado: false,
        realizado: false
        },
        {
        title: 'Resina2',
        subtitle: 'Fecha2', 
        Price: '#162',
        pagado: false,
        realizado: false
        }]

        const handleOnClick = () => {
            setFragments(arreglo)
        }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Fragments:</h1>
            <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Agregar</button>
            {fragments.map( fragment => (
                <ChildComponent 
                    fragment={fragment}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Eso seria el componente padre, yo le he puesto un boton para que muestre los objetos cuando se pulsa, este boton agrega los objetos al state fragments y se muestran en pantalla. Luego recorro ese arreglo enviando los diferentes fragments via props y mostrando todas las propiedades de cada objeto en un componente hijo que contiene todo el html para no repetir código. Observa como he puesto las propiedades pagado y realizado en false.

El componente hijo seria algo asi:

```
const ChildComponent = ({fragment}) => {

    const {title, subtitle, price, pagado, realizado} = fragment

    const [statePagado, setStatePagado] = useState(pagado)
    const [stateRealizado, setStateRealizado] = useState(realizado)

    const handleOnClickPagado = () => {
        setStatePagado(!statePagado)
    }
    const handleOnClickRealizado = () => {
        setStateRealizado(!stateRealizado)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>{subtitle}</p>
            <p>{price}</p>
            <button 
                className={statePagado ? 'green' : 'red'} onClick={handleOnClickPagado}
            >Pagado</button>
            <button 
                className={stateRealizado ? 'green' : 'red'} onClick={handleOnClickRealizado}
            >Realizado</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Aplico destructuring del prop fragment, y utilizo la propiedad pagado y realizado para crear dos states con el valor inicial, que luego se modifica llamando a la funcion handleOnClick que se encarga de cambiarle el valor.

[image: Ejemplo]

Esto es un ejemplo sencillo, te quedan problemas por resolver como añadirle una key a cada objeto que vallas a pasar por props, idear la forma de modificar el objeto para que te guarde si las propiedades pagado y realizado son true o false.... pero eso es lo divertido y te lo dejo a ti :)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias :3

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario ya lo intente en otra ventana todo desde un mismo componente pero no logro hacerlo xs

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7vXY4m9G Este es el codigo completo de ese componente

Comment: Me parace que has creado un componente muy grande, y mi consejo es que dividas el componente. Por otro lado, en las lineas 367, y 377 llamas dos veces a la función handleOnClickPagado, esto te lo pondra primero en true, y luego otra vez en false. Por otro lado, en la linea 368 y y 379 intentas cambiar el valor del state fragmen (cosa que no se debe hacer de esa forma, si no utilizando el setFragment) y con la función handleOnClick vuelves a sobreescribir el fragment con el arreglo, que no has modificado. Primero debes modificar el arreglo y luego con setFragment cambiar el state.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera seria crear un state de arreglo de objetos, en donde almacenes las propiedades de cada etiqueta (en base a este arreglo puedes imprimirlo en pantalla), y en el onClick() de cada etiqueta que mande a una funcion para modificar la propiedad de pagado de la etiqueta (0bjeto) correspondiente en el state.

Comment: Lo intentare muchas gracias